# Error report - ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis 00907. 00000 - "missing right parenthesis

Tags: sql, oracle

I need help. I'm relatively new to SQL coding.

I need to create View of:
The number of meters read in the current month by each of the meter readers (this view should be able to be used at any time without having to be changed to accommodate the date).

And I have this code

```
CREATE VIEW ViewA AS
SELECT SUM(meter) FROM reading
WHERE MONTH(columnName) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE());
```

But the error says:
Error starting at line : 1 in command -
CREATE VIEW ViewA AS
SELECT SUM(meter) FROM reading
WHERE MONTH = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE())
Error report -
ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
00907. 00000 -  "missing right parenthesis"
*Cause:
*Action:

Answer (score 0):

`MONTH` is not an Oracle function and you do not want the braces after `CURRENT_DATE` and you need to give the aggregated value an alias.

```sql
CREATE VIEW ViewA AS
SELECT SUM(meter) AS total_reading
FROM reading
WHERE  EXTRACT( MONTH FROM columnName) = EXTRACT( MONTH FROM CURRENT_DATE );
```

However, that would aggregate the current month from any year. If you just want the current month then:

```sql
CREATE VIEW ViewA AS
SELECT SUM(meter) AS total_reading
FROM reading
WHERE  columnName >= TRUNC( CURRENT_DATE, 'MM' )
AND    columnName <  ADD_MONTHS( TRUNC( CURRENT_DATE, 'MM' ), 1 );
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=64e544b742e3214b3c5ba24db797e99d)*

However, your "homework" question is:

> The number of meters read in the current month by each of the meter readers

You are not finding this; you probably want to use `COUNT` rather than `SUM` and you want to use `GROUP BY` to get a value for each meter reader (but you haven't given the table definition so it is unclear which column you should group by).

But something like:

```sql
CREATE VIEW ViewA AS
SELECT meter_reader,
       COUNT(meter) AS num_meters_read
FROM   reading
WHERE  columnName >= TRUNC( CURRENT_DATE, 'MM' )
AND    columnName <  ADD_MONTHS( TRUNC( CURRENT_DATE, 'MM' ), 1 )
GROUP BY meter_reader;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need each of the meter readers, you will need aggregation:

```
CREATE VIEW ViewA AS
    SELECT meter_reader, SUM(meter)
    FROM reading
    WHERE TRUNC(date_column, 'Month') = TRUNC(sysdate, 'Month')
    GROUP BY meter_reader -- whatever that column is
```

In general, this would be more efficient written as:

```
CREATE VIEW ViewA AS
    SELECT meter_reader, SUM(meter)
    FROM reading
    WHERE date_column >= TRUNC(sysdate, 'Month') AND
          date_column < TRUNC(sysdate, 'Month') + INTERVAL '1' MONTH
    GROUP BY meter_reader -- whatever that column is
```